# Making text visible again after it's been hidden by a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've currently got a button that drops down and is meant to show new text / hide the old header. I've currently got my code set up as

```
$('a.btn-navbar').click(function(){
            $('header#header-top').css('height','');
            $('#headerContainer').css('height','');
             $('#headerText').css('visibility','hidden');
        });
```

how would I go about reenabling headertext when the button is clicked again to hide the drop down menu button?

I was thinking about using toggle but I'm not 100% sure on it works and thought it would be best to get an opinion.

Edit. I used the .toggle() to get it to work. The issue I had before why I wasn't using this was that it slightly overlapped the button I needed for the drop down. Adding z-index:-1; allowed me to get around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example :

```
$('a.btn-navbar').click(function(){
            $('header#header-top').css('height','');
            $('#headerContainer').css('height','');
             $('#headerText').toggle();
        });
```

Comment: `.toggle()` will use the css property `display` not `visible`

Comment: Indeed, It depends of what you need to do.

Comment: This also works fine for what I'm trying to achieve. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write a condition with ternary operator,

```
$('a.btn-navbar').click(function(){
   var header = $('#headerText');
   header.css('visibility',header.css('visibility') === 'hidden' ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
});
```

or do it with .toggleClass(),

to write a condition with ternary operator,

```
.visible { visibility:visible; }
.hidden { visibility:hidden; }

$('a.btn-navbar').click(function(){
   var header = $('#headerText');
   header.toggleClass('hidden visible');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use (:visible) selector
$('a.btn-navbar').click(function(){

```
         if ( $("#headerText").is(":visible") ) 
          {
            $('header#header-top').css('height','');
            $('#headerContainer').css('height','');
            $('#headerText').hide();
          }else{
            $('#headerText').show();
         }
    });
```